# set variable value in another variable name

Tags: jquery, variables, onclick

I want to take the id of a div and set that value at the end of a jquery variable name. For example if I click on a div with an id of "2", I want the function to create a variable called  "var doThis2" instead of just "var doThis"

Here is my code as of now:

```
    var clickedComment = false;
    $('.comment').click(function (event) {

        var id = event.target.id;  
        // I am wanting ^this id value to be added to the end on clickedComment  

        if (clickedComment == true) {
            $("." + id).animate({ left: '+=85.2%' }, 250);
            clickedComment = false;
        } else {
            $("." + id).animate({ left: '-=85.2%' }, 250);
            clickedComment = true;
        }
    });
```

Any help or even a more efficient way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* do this with `eval`, but I'm not sure you would actually want to do that. Why not store the clicked state in a regular object? E.g.

```
var clickedComments = {};
```

And then use this:

```
$('.comment').click(function (event) {
    var id = event.target.id;

    if (clickedComments[id] == true) {
        $("." + id).animate({ left: '+=85.2%' }, 250);
        clickedComments[id] = false;
    } else {
        $("." + id).animate({ left: '-=85.2%' }, 250);
        clickedComments[id] = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: I got my code to work with Paul Grime's recommendation but I had to adjust a few things. Here is my final working code:

    var clickedComment = {};
    var id;

    $('.comment').hover(function (event) {
        id = event.target.id;
        clickedComment[id];
    });

    $('.comment').click(function (event) {
        if (clickedComment[id] == true) {
            $("." + id).animate({ left: '+=85.2%' }, 250);
            clickedComment[id] = false;
        } else {
            $("." + id).animate({ left: '-=85.2%' }, 250);
            clickedComment[id] = true;
        }
    });
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

`var myArrayOfVars['vardoThis'+id] = value`

and then you can access ur variable with : `myArrayOfVars['vardoThis'+id]`